# Highcharter custom candlestick Rule using R

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I'm trying to implement a custom rule considering the ups and downs for the candle pattern using Highcharter library for stocks, but i'm not really sure if it's possible.

Checking the API documentation  the candlestick color and custom items are undefined.

Dos anyone ever tried do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement module [pattern-fill](https://code.highcharts.com/modules/pattern-fill.js) and then you will get possibility to add pattern directly in [series.color](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.candlestick.color).

```
  color: {
    pattern: {
      path: {
        d: 'M-1 1 l2 -2 M0 16 l16 -16 M15 17 l8 -8',
        strokeWidth: 2
      },
      color: '#00ff00',
      width: 16,
      height: 16
    }
  },
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wkso43za/